# Semi transparent PictureBox c#

Tags: c#, picturebox, transparent

I want to make a PictureBox semi transparent: show the conent of a picturebox on the back put not the base color of the form.

**My Project**

[image]

The little PictureBoxs that are on the front shows the back color of the form (control) (it have "Transparent" as background color), but I want to show color Red (the background image of the big PictureBox). How can I do it?

Comment: Tough ask with WinForms, not kidding, I'm serious...

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144371/a-picturebox-problem) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747926/override-a-transparent-picturebox-in-c-sharp-windows-application-form).

Comment: You see the Parent in the background.  Usually the form, never another PictureBox unless you assign the Parent property in code.  Check the PictureContainer class in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387562/17034).

Comment: No tranparency in winforms unless with __nested__ controls. To nest inside a PB you need to code it, as Hans said..: `picBoxSmall1.Parent = picBoxbig; picBoxSamll.Location = ....`

Comment: Is the red box a Picturebox?

Comment: the red box is a PictureBox with a bagkground image.

Answer (score 1):

This may not exactly answer you question, if it is not helpful, I can delete my answer.  I am not sure if I completely understood.  If your background image is going to be a simple PictureBox with a single color, the following should code work.

`pictureBox1` - an image of a simple star

[image]

`pictureBox2` - my red background image

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap("Star.png");
b.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
pictureBox1.Image = b;
pictureBox1.BackColor = pictureBox2.BackColor;
```

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: This code works if the background image is not a simple color? for example a map of some world region